# How to delete photos from iPhone 5 without removing already transferred photos from iMac?

Tags: macos, data-synchronization, photos

I have synced my photos from iPhone 5 to an iMac (running Mavericks).

Now I would like to remove the photos from the phone but I'm not sure how the syncing works. Will the photos stay on the iMac or will the removed photos be removed from the computer when the next sync occurs?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! @Jawa has substantially edited your question to attempt to clarify your intent, but please add more detail including whether you are referring to iPhoto or Aperture, and whether you synced the photos through iCloud, iTunes or another method.

Answer (score 1):

Were you transferring photos from your iPhone to your Mac using Photo Stream? If you were, no matter what happens to your photos on your iPhone, the transferred photos will always be on your Mac.

Because the Mac would most definetly have more storage space than an iOS device, Photo Stream photos are automatically downloaded and permanently saved to your Mac's iPhoto or Aperture library; the 1000 photo/30 day limit doesn't apply for OS X or Windows unless you clear the photos and start fresh.

If you moved or copied your photos from your Photo Stream to somewhere else on your Mac, they are still safe.